# PROMQL: how to add values when there is no data returned?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a data model where some metrics are namespaced by client, environment and deployment name. I am interested in creating a summary of each deployment, where that summary is based on the number of alerts that are present for each deployment.

I can get the deployments in the `dev`, `uat`, and `prod` environments using this query:

```
group by(tenant, environment, deployment)(up{environment=~"dev|uat|prod"}) - 1

# returns the following by way of example:
{deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1"}   0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant3"}  0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant2"}  0
{deployment="default",environment="uat",tenant="tenant1"}   0
```

So we can see that tenant 1 has 2 deployments in 2 different environments, whereas the other 2 have only one.  `group by` returns a value of 1, so we subtract 1 to get 0 for each deployment and I now wish to add to this the number of alerts that are applicable to each deployment.

To get the alerts, I do this:

```
ALERTS{severity="warning"}
# returns something like this when there is an alert, the details in the alert will vary, but will always have the `tenant`, `environment` and `deployment` labels
ALERTS{alertname="HostSystemdServiceCrashed",alertstate="firing",instance="example",job="node",deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1",name="example.service",severity="warning",state="failed",type="oneshot"} 1

# however, when there are no alerts, I get "no data" returned
```

I can't work out how to add the alerts to the deployments whilst retaining the deployments for which there were no alerts returned:

```
(group by(tenant, environment, deployment)(up{environment=~"dev|uat|prod"}) -1)  + on(tenant, environment, deployment) (ALERTS{severity="warning"})

# returns only data for the deployment for which there is an alert
{deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1"} 1

# if there are no alerts, I get no data returned at all
```

What I want as output is this:

```
{deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1"} 1
{deployment="default",environment="uat",tenant="tenant1"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant2"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant3"} 0
```

How can I achieve this?

**NOTE:**

If I use `sum` with `or`, then I get this, depending on the order of the arguments to `or`:

```
(group by(tenant, environment, deployment)(up{environment=~"dev|uat|prod"}) -1)  or sum by (tenant, environment, deployment) (ALERTS{severity="warning"} )

# returns this, note the value in `tenant1|dev|default`
{deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="uat",tenant="tenant1"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant2"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant3"} 0
```

If I reverse the order of the parameters to `or`, I get what I am after:

```
{deployment="default",environment="dev",tenant="tenant1"} 1
{deployment="default",environment="uat",tenant="tenant1"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant2"} 0
{deployment="default",environment="prod",tenant="tenant3"} 0
```

But I'm stuck now if I want to do something like apply a weight to alerts of a different severity level, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
summary = 0 + sum(warning alerts) + 2*sum(alerts(critical alerts))
```

This gives the same single value series, or no data if there are no alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a proper way to do this, but in the end, I used `label_replace` to add an arbitrary key-value label to each sub-query that I wished to add to the original values, and then applied an `or` to each. This had the effect of merging the series without overwriting any values. I was then able to perform a final `sum by` over the resulting series to reduce the results down to a single result, dropping the ad-hoc labels in the process.

```
sum(
  (group by(tenant, environment, deployment) (up{environment=~"dev|uat|prod"} ) -1) 

  or label_replace((sum (ALERTS{severity="warning"} ) by (tenant, environment, deployment)), "severity", "warning", "", "") or 

  2 * label_replace((sum (ALERTS{severity="critical"} )  by (tenant, environment, deployment)), "severity", "critical", "", "")
) by (tenant, environment, deployment)
```